# redirect to another website this url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this 2 links as example :

```
http://thisismysite.com/news/news.aspx?id=2221
http://thisismysite.com/news/news.aspx?id=4321
etc etc
```

If you open this link it should redirect you to another website with same  parameters :

```
http://otherwebsite.com/news/news.aspx?id=2221
http://otherwebsite.com/news/news.aspx?id=4321
```

Is this possible ?

Thank you

Comment: If this is possible? Yes, it is. But we need more data in order to help you do that. What server are you using, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PHP, you can use this :

```
header('Location:http://newdomain.com'. $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

With htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay Vincent , i think i exlained wrong my problem . I actually want to redirect all url's on my website to another site only if they have that parameter " id= " at the end . Is that possible ?

Comment: Just use a condition : `if (isset($_GET['id'])) { // redirect }`

Comment: Thanks man this worked :) "if (isset($_GET['id'])) { // redirect }" .. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a 301 redirect for the entire domain, if the get param `id` is present with a numeric value.

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=[0-9](&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherwebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay , im actually trying to redirect only the urls on my website that have that prameter "id=" at the end of url . Basically if you visit a link on my site http://thisismysite.com/news/news.aspx?id=3451 it should redirect you to the other website but with same ?id= wich is 3451 in my example .. Is that possible ? Hopefully im clear

Comment: You need to match against the %{QUERY_STRING}